# Back button Not Working in BB10 QML File

Tags: button, blackberry-10, back

I am trying to implement a basic back button in my app.

I am using web view in a page.

Added a button and code I found from a forum.

```
   Button {
        id: button1
        text: "Back"
        onClicked: {
            WebView.goBack();
        }
```

am I missing something?

Comment: How will this button find the object with the id 'WebView'?  When you run this does the device log show anything - like 'WebView not found'?

Answer (score 0):

this is simple code

main.qml

```
import bb.cascades 1.0
NavigationPane {
    id: nav
    Page {
        id: pg
        titleBar: TitleBar {
            id: tb
            title: "Mini Web Browser"


        }

        Container {layout:StackLayout {
                orientation:LayoutOrientation.TopToBottom
        }
        Container {

            layout:StackLayout {
                orientation:LayoutOrientation.LeftToRight
            }
            TextField {
                id:tf
                hintText: "Enter you Url"
                inputMode: TextFieldInputMode.Url
                input.submitKey: SubmitKey.Go

                layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
                    spaceQuota: 5
                }

            }
            Button {
                id:go
                imageSource: "asset:///ic_done.png"
                layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
                    spaceQuota: 1
                }
                onClicked: {
                    console.log(tf.text);
                    console.log(myWebView.urlChanged(tf.text))

                }
            }


        }
        ScrollView {
            scrollViewProperties.pinchToZoomEnabled: true
            scrollViewProperties.scrollMode: ScrollMode.Both
            WebView {
                id:myWebView
                url: "https://www.google.com/search?q="+tf.text 
                settings.devicePixelRatio: 1.0

                onLoadingChanged: {
                    if (loadRequest.status ==  WebLoadStatus.Started ) {
                        statusLabel.setText("Loading start..................")
                        tb.title=myWebView.title
                        statusLabel.visible=true

                    }
                    else if (loadRequest.status ==  WebLoadStatus.Succeeded ) {
                        statusLabel.setText("Loading finished.")
                        statusLabel.visible=false
                        tb.title=myWebView.title                                   
                    }
                    else if (loadRequest.status ==  WebLoadStatus.Failed ) {
                        statusLabel.setText("Load failed.")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ProgressIndicator {
            id: pi
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Fill                       
            fromValue:0
            toValue: 100
            value:myWebView.loadProgress
            onValueChanged: {
                if(value<100)
                    pi.visible=true 
                else if(value== 100)
                    pi.visible=false


            }
        }

        Label{
            id: statusLabel
            verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Bottom
            horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Fill
            text: "ram"    
            //visible: 
            textStyle.textAlign: TextAlign.Left
            textStyle.color: Color.Black
        }

        }


        actions:[
            ActionItem {

                enabled: myWebView.canGoBack
                title: "Back"
                ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.OnBar
                imageSource: "asset:///ic_previous.png"

                onTriggered: {  
                    myWebView.goBack()

                }

            },

            ActionItem {
                title: "Forword"
                enabled: myWebView.canGoForward
                ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.OnBar
                imageSource: "asset:///ic_next.png"  
                onTriggered: {  myWebView.goForward();  

                }

            },

            ActionItem {
                title:myWebView.loading ? "Stop" : "Reload"

                ActionBar.placement: ActionBarPlacement.OnBar
                imageSource:myWebView.loading ?  "asset:///ic_cancel.png" : "asset:///ic_rotate.png"
                onTriggered: {myWebView.loading ? myWebView.stop():myWebView.reload();

                }

            } 
        ]
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for a Help page which gets loaded with HTML from the assets directory which may contain links to the application website for additional information. Peter's comment may be your solution. In this case the back button is placed in the TitleBar, but it could as easily be place in the action bar, overflow menu or other location.

```
import bb.cascades 1.0

Page {
    titleBar: TitleBar {
        title: "Help"
        scrollBehavior: TitleBarScrollBehavior.NonSticky
        dismissAction: ActionItem {
            title: "Close"
            onTriggered: {
                helpSheet.close();
            }
            imageSource: "asset:///images/ic_cancel.png"
        }
        acceptAction: ActionItem {
            title: "Back"
            enabled: webView.canGoBack
            onTriggered: {
                webView.goBack();
            }
        }
    }

    id: helpPage
    objectName: "helpSheet"
    ScrollView {
        Container {
            layout: StackLayout {
            }
            WebView {
                id: webView
                url: "local:///assets/help.html"
                layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
            }
            topMargin: 21.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```